# Could Ted Cruz (or another sitting senator) be appointed to be a SCOTUS justice?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, judiciary

Donald Trump made a list of possible US Supreme Court appointments if a vacancy shows up while he's in office. Two of these intrigued me: Tom Cotton and Ted Cruz.

I know this might not matter in practice because ideology/party is enough justification.

Could a US president pick a sitting US senator to be a Supreme Court justice? And, does Ted Cruz specifically have significant legal experience?

Comment: I think this answers the main question. As for Ted Cruz, wikipedia says he [graduated _magna cum laud_ from Harvard Law School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Cruz#Education) and [clerked for Chief Justice William Rehnquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Cruz#Clerkships), so he does have legal experience

Comment: Not directly related, but interesting: [Taft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Howard_Taft) was both President and then later Chief Justice.

Comment: Is this a question about whether they can be nominated while serving in the Senate, or is it a question of whether they can continue to serve if approved? The latter would render them useless as justices because of recusals, I would think, even if it was somehow allowed.

Comment: I suggest this question may not have been closed so quickly.   The "duplicate" deals with a substantially more general question of qualifications to serve as a Justice, and not the aspect of separation of powers.    A more specific answer could be more informative, for example citing the example of Justice Hugo Black, who was appointed in 1937.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the Constitution does not spell out ANY requirements for being appointed to the Supreme Court, so in theory Trump could nominate anyone, including his wife or his youngest son, or even emulate the Roman emperor Caligula and nominate his horse (if he had a horse, of course).   Getting the Senate to confirm the nomination is the problem :-)

Comment: Hugo Black was confirmed in a similarly politically charged situation.

Comment: @Burt_Harris I suggested that as a duplicate because I thought the question NumberFile had was about the general question of qualifications. I think I was right as they agreed with the duplicate (that's what "closed as duplicate by community" means). If there are interesting separation of powers issues here, though, feel free to ask another question based around that. I usually feel like that gets a better result than trying to shoehorn it into a question when that's not really what the OP was interested in